# Copy to Primary Selection in VIM

Tags: command-line, google-chrome, vim, clipboard

I tried "+y and "*y but both doesn't seem to copy into the primary selection.

Note that `vim --version` returns `-clipboard`. Not sure what this means.
Also note that I'm running VIM in a terminal.

So how do I copy text into the Primary Selection in VIM?
Goal is to copy text from VIM into Google Chrome.

Comment: If the output of `vim --version` returns `-clipboard`, that means that your vim installation doesn't include the clipboard feature. A `+` means that the feature is installed.

Comment: Ok. But it doens't mean that it cannot copy to the primary selection, right?

Comment: I think you can't. AFAIK, "clipboard"/"primary selection" is a feature of the X server. Vim itself is a pure terminal application and has nothing to do with your X server. But I may be wrong in this point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a version of vim that has `+clipboard` in its version. Install the `vim-gnome` package and you should be fine. (And you don't have to use gvim to use the clipboard, it still works when running vim in a terminal.)

**Note**
In more recent versions, the actual package name seems to be `vim-gtk` and `vim-gtk3` respectively (`vim-gnome` is a dummy package).

Comment: installing vim-gnome did it, even with -clipboard

Answer (score 2):

`"+y` uses a special register and is part of the `clipboard` feature of vim. Since your version of vim doesn't support clipboard (`-clipboard` means, clipboard feature isn't available), you need to use something else.

You can try [this plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2098), which doesn't depend on the `clipboard` feature and should work in the pure terminal version of vim. It seems that it depends on one of the programs `screen`, `xclip`, `tmux`.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04 was having one of the graphical packages installed (`vim-gtk` or `vim-gtk3`) **and remove** the package `vim`. This will set the alternative for `vim` from `/usr/bin/vim.basic` to e. g. `/usr/bin/vim.gtk`.

The alternative can also be selected manually with

```
 $ sudo update-alternatives --config vim
```

Answer (score 0):

If your vim has the clipboard support you can:

```
:%y*

* .............. primary selection
```