# What are the differences between the different vim packages available in Ubuntu?

Tags: vim, gvim

The difference between `vim-gtk` and `vim-gnome` has been discussed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33260/difference-between-vim-gtk-and-vim-gnome).

Ubuntu usually offers more than these two options for vim, e.g.:

- `vim-nox`
- `vim-athena`
- `vim-*`

It is not clear which `vim` package have which dependecies and which one is preferable to use on one's system. I keep my `vim` configuration files (`~/.vim` folder) on GitHub and clone it on any system I have to work on. They work with `vim-gnome` but will they work with any of these distributions?

Can we have the major differences listed out between all of the possible `vim` candidates available on Ubuntu so one can make an informed decision?

Comment: so which vim you ended up installing ? im on ubuntu 12.04... was thinking of athena or gnome. they seem to do the same thing.

Comment: vim-gtk for KDE: http://askubuntu.com/a/33266/9081

Comment: I am using `vim-athena` (if I have to use gui client). I've also used `vim-gnome`. These days I mostly stay in terminal with `vim` and uses GUI rarely.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

Including the `vim` package, there appear to be at least six "vim-variants" (not including available documentation, or plugin packages) as well as the main `vim` package in both the `main` and `universe` repositories.

Below is a brief summary of each (links go to package description and dependencies in Ubuntu LTS release 20.04 "Focal"):

- [**vim**](http://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/vim)

Vim compiled and set up with a rather standard set of features. This package does not provide a GUI version of Vim or scripting language support. See the other vim-* packages if you need more (or less).

In order to install this package, run `sudo apt-get install vim`

- [**jvim-canna**](http://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/jvim-canna) - *Japanized VIM (Canna version)*

This package allows the entering of Kanji from the console.

In order to install this package, run `sudo apt-get install jvim-canna`

Depends upon the `libcanna1g` library

Does not appear to support Perl, Python, Ruby, or TCL scripting.

- [**vim-athena**](http://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/vim-athena) - enhanced vi editor - compiled with an Athena GUI

  This package is compiled with the [Athena GUI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Athena) as opposed to GTK+ or Gnome.

  See [this askubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/169046/106495) for additional details.

  In order to install this package, run `sudo apt-get install vim-athena`

  Supports Perl, Python, Ruby, and TCL scripting.
- [**vim-gnome**](http://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/vim-gnome)/[**vim-gtk3**](http://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/vim-gtk3) - enhanced vi editor - compiled with a GNOME GUI (GTK2 before 17.10, GTK3 from 17.10)

  In order to install this package, run `sudo apt-get install vim-gnome`

  Depends upon the `libgnome2` library

  Supports Perl, Python, Ruby, and TCL scripting.
- [**vim-gtk**](http://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/vim-gtk) - enhanced vi editor - compiled with the GTK2 GUI

  Used in KDE/Kubuntu-like environments

  In order to install this package, run `sudo apt-get install vim-gtk`

  Supports Perl, Python, Ruby, and TCL scripting.
- [**vim-nox**](http://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/vim-nox) - enhanced vi editor

  Like vim-tiny, vim-nox is a minimal vim installation and does not have a GUI. It comes with mouse support, but no clipboard support, IIRC.

  In order to install this package, run `sudo apt-get install vim-nox`

  Supports Perl, Python, Ruby, and TCL scripting.
- [**vim-tiny**](http://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/vim-tiny) - enhanced vi editor - compact version

  vim-tiny is included as the default vim on Ubuntu distributions and comes with many optional features disabled(e.g. multi-level undo).

  See [this askubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/104202/106495) for details on its feature set(or lack thereof).

  In order to install this package, run `sudo apt-get install vim-tiny`

  Does not support Perl, Python, Ruby, or TCL scripting.

  As close to being [vi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi) without being [vi](http://people.cis.ksu.edu/%7Ebhoward/vi/vi10.html).

---

Locally, to see which features are supported in a particular installed vim package, running the following command: `vim --version` will provide a list of features included(or excluded) in the particular package.

For example, on my system I can run either `vim --version`, `vim.tiny --version`, or `vim.athena --version` to see the differences in their respective supported features.  The Debian/Ubuntu `/etc/alternatives` system determines which vim package executes when you run`vi` or `vim`, see [What is etc/alternatives used for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/484561/what-is-etc-alternatives-used-for)

---

### Python support

Before 16.04, the above packages (other than `vim-tiny`) included Vim with scripting support for Python 2. In 16.04, they all support Python 3, and there are corresponding `*-py2` packages ([`vim-gnome-py2`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/vim-gnome-py2), for example) which provide a Vim command with Python 2 support. Both can be installed together, and the commands will be, for example, `vim.gnome` and `vim.gnome-py2` respectively. Otherwise, the `*-py2` packages provide the same feature set as the corresponding packages. Python 2 support was removed after 16.04.

Comment: vim.nox does not look like a minimal vim installation but rather a classic vim with support for extra scripting languages: `vim.nox --version` shows the same set of features as `vim.basic` but with +tcl +ruby +lua +perl. Python is supported in both versions.

Comment: no gui (only terminal) seems enought minimal for me. Extra scripting languages are need for some cool plugins out there.

Comment: Also package 'vim': This package contains a version of vim compiled with a rather standard set of features. This package does not provide a GUI version of Vim. See the other vim-* packages if you need more (or less). Source - https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/vim/

Comment: I recently realized that some of above may or may not have `+clipboard` in their compile flags. Clipboard is an important feature for developers. Probably a good idea to list out what else might be missing by default in different packages at least from developer point of view.

Comment: what about vim-gtk3 vs vim-gnome?

Comment: @MarkStosberg You are welcome to edit the answer. vim-gnome is included in my answer. You can certainly update the answer as new releases occur.

Comment: @KevinBowen I could, but I'm not really sure why GTK builds exist vs the Gnome builds. For example, what's the difference the "gtk2 gui" build vs the "gnome2 gui" build in terms of features or appearance?

Comment: It may be worth noting that when you've got installed one of the graphical packages, you don't need the basic `vim` anymore and might want to remove it to avoid conflicts and confusion. See https://askubuntu.com/a/1106538/568304

Comment: Are there any speed advantages to one versus another? For example, if I want to open a large (say, 2GB) csv file in vim, does one graphical package win over another?