# which vim should I use in xubuntu / Ubuntu+XFCE?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, vim

Which vim should I use in xubuntu / Ubuntu+XFCE?

My current system is Ubuntu, but I have replaced the Unity interface with XFCE (via `sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop`).  There is no vim installed at the moment:

```
$ vim --version
The program 'vim' can be found in the following packages:
 * vim
 * vim-gnome
 * vim-tiny
 * vim-athena
 * vim-gtk
 * vim-nox
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

I might have thought to use vim-gtk, but I'm not exactly sure--[this guide here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/281886/what-is-the-difference-between-the-different-vim-packages-available-in-ubuntu/281972#281972) apparently suggests `vim-gtk` is for users of KDE/Kubuntu.  Which one should I install?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Install `vim` if you want the text-mode interface or `vim-gtk` if you want the GUI.

Basically `vim-gtk` is the GUI version for anybody who doesn't want to install the Gnome2 libraries on which `vim-gnome` depends and doesn't like the 1990s style of `vim-athena`