# Why does vi start vim but typing vim says vim needs to be installed?

Tags: command-line, vim

When I type `vi` into terminal, VIM starts up. But when I type `vim` into terminal, the terminal says `The program 'vim' can be found in the following packages:` and lists different varieties of vim, as if I don't have vim installed. Is there a reason for this? Is the `vi` that comes with ubuntu not the same as VIM?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, you do have `vim` installed, but a minimal version of it called `vim-tiny`. If you run `vim.tiny`, you'll find it runs. This version has very few features enabled, and therefore doesn't provide the `vim` command. The other packages, `vim-nox`, `vim-gnome`, `vim-gtk`, `vim-athena`, have more features, and provide the `vim` command.

The `vi` command itself is actually a symbolic link, and points to whichever preferred version is installed through the [Debian alternatives system](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianAlternatives). By default, since only `vim-tiny` is installed, the only alternative is `vim.tiny`, and running `vi` actually runs `vim.tiny`. If you install one of the other packages, they will become the preferred alternative for `vi`.

Related:

- [What are the differences between the different vim packages available in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/281886/158442)