# Is it possible to have both vi and vim installed so that they can be used separately?

Tags: command-line, software-installation, vim, vi

I can't use `vi`, well, I can, but I would much prefer `vim`, however I need to share a computer with someone who hates `vim` and can only use `vi`...

After installing `vim` I find that if I use the `vi` command it just opens `vim`, so is there any way to have them both installed at the same time but have it so that both can be used and they stay separate?

The machine will have Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18 running on it.

**Clarification:** As this seems to have confused some I will state it more clearly here, I wish for `vi` to point to `/usr/bin/vim.tiny` and for `vim` to point to `/usr/bin/vim.basic`.

Comment: Install one through Software Center or Terminal, and the other compile from source.

You can even install both packages and have the binaries links point to the correct binary.

Comment: @LnxSlck: Is there any way of doing it if both are installed through Terminal (not from source)?

Comment: vi doesn't exist anymore, default is vim. tiny if that's what your friend wants. That exists, that never disappears if you install vim. There's also nvi which is the closest to original vi

Comment: @Serg: Is there any way to have them both installed under different users or something and then have it so that `vi` accesses `vi` under the user who has it, and then `vim` accesses `vim` under the user who has it? Or a similar system of sorts?

Comment: I don't mind if it's crazy and elaborate, just as long as it works... :D

Comment: The original `vi` is not available easily on Ubuntu. Can you clarify with the idiot what exactly they want from `vi`? What system is the idiot using where they can access `vi`?

Comment: If your someone that you are sharing a computer with prefers `vi` to `vim`, I hardly imagine that they will be OK with using GNOME.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda you can have aliases for each user in `.bashrc` . For example, for your friend you can make `alias vi = vim.tiny`

Comment: @Serg: That would be a nice thing.

Comment: @muru: `vi` is installed by default on Ubuntu, is it not?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda `vim-tiny` is.

Comment: ParanoidPanda , I already told you but you probably didn't see : `vi`  , the real vi does not exist anymore. It's gone a long with the days of old Unix systems.  By default Ubuntu uses `vim.tiny` , the trimmed down version of `vim`.  This is what muru is referent to

Comment: @muru: Well, my friend is pretty sure that he is using the original...

Comment: @Serg: Ok, well my friend must be confused then... Anyhow, I want `vim`, and he probably wants that `vim.tiny` thing...

Comment: @ParanoidPanda Unless someone compiled and installed it, he's not using the original vi on Ubuntu. He might be using Arch Linux, which uses this port: http://ex-vi.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Given the edit, I fail to see what more my answer needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been already explained what is the difference between `vim` and `vim.tiny`, and your friend will somewhat have to break his beliefs and get up to speed with the times, because what he or she really wants is `vim.tiny`

Like I've mentioned in the comments, ask your friend to make an alias for him/her self  in `.bashrc`

```
alias vi = vim.tiny
```

That way he or she can use the minimalistic version of `vi` while you can continue using `vim`.

Additional small setup that you may need is to `$ cp /etc/vim/vimrc.tiny  ~/.vimrc`

In case they want the "real vi"  you can `sudo apt-get install nvi` and alias `vi` to `nvi`. `nvi` is the closest to the original.

Comment: Hmm, no, [`ex-vi`](http://ex-vi.sourceforge.net/) is the closest, since it is a port. `nvi` is a clone.

Answer (score 3):

As user1326419 notes, `vi` is part of the Debian alternatives system. To change what `vi` runs, do:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config vi
There are 3 choices for the alternative vi (providing /usr/bin/vi).

  Selection    Path                Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/vim.gnome   60        auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/vim.basic   30        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/vim.gnome   60        manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/vim.tiny    10        manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 3
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/vim.tiny to provide /usr/bin/vi (vi) in manual mode
```

---

Then:

```
$ vi --version| head -5
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Jan  2 2014 19:39:02)
Included patches: 1-52
Modified by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
Compiled by buildd@
Small version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
$ vim --version| head -5     
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Jan  2 2014 19:39:47)
Included patches: 1-52
Modified by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
Compiled by buildd@
Huge version with GTK2-GNOME GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
```

`vim.tiny` is the minimal version you get when you first install Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

This was answered by @muru in this question ([Why does vi start vim but typing vim says vim needs to be installed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/641102/why-does-vi-start-vim-but-typing-vim-says-vim-needs-to-be-installed?rq=1))

> The vi command itself is actually a symbolic link, and points to whichever preferred version is installed through the Debian alternatives system.

--- Edit to include my comment below and answer the question ---

Change the sym link in /etc/alternatives for vi to point to your installation of vi. The sym link for vim should point at your installtion of vim

Comment: I don't need to know why, I need to know how to make it work differently.

Comment: Change the sym link in /etc/alternatives for vi to point to your installation of vi. The sym link for vim should point at your installtion of vim